# Monaco editor: completion provider conflict

Tags: javascript, html, css, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco Editor in a web project and I want to:

- use `HTML` as language to provide completions and highlighting for the text
- use custom `{{...}}` placeholders to provide some custom data

The problem is that the HTML language provides completion for `{` bracket ending with `}` for `CSS` styles, and it conflicts with my `{{` bracket completion. Is there the possibility to use both or disable the HTML single `{` bracket completion?